# Wrap line instead of overfull hbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, justification

Is there any way I can tell LaTeX to try to do the normal full-justification *if at all possible*, but in worst case (if the h-box would otherwise be overfull), to just line-break early and leave a ragged right?

Comment: In the worst case `\raggedright`, indeed. In less serious cases, it comes to my mind: not use big fonts in narrow columns,  allow hyphenation whenever possible (set  `hyphenpenalty`, `\exhyphenpenalty`, `\pretolerance`, `\tolerance`, `\righthyphenmin`, `\lefthyphenmin`, use \hyphenation or `\-` for unknown words), use the `microtype` package,  rewrite the text, set  `\emergencystretch`, set `\fontdimen3`, `\fontdimen4` and `\fontdimen7` and ... Have I said already rewrite the text?

Comment: @Fran That's a less than ideal solution, especially because this is text generated by biblatex. I would think TeX should be able to automate this.

Comment: An overfull `\hbox` mean that LaTeX already tried to do the normal full-justification automatically,   but for some reason it not possible.  So you must change something to make it possible. For a bibliography,  the  problem is the same,  and the solutions too, (obviously except  the rewrite of  the text).

Comment: @Fran But there is non (hypothetical) reason that LaTeX could not simply fall back on leaving a ragged right instead of complaining about an overfull hbox. Is it possible to implement such behaviour?

Comment: Of course, except when some word is longer that a line width, LaTeX always can  justify, even without  hyphens, and avoid any overfull `\hbox` making a line break whenever needed. This is exactly what `\raggedright` does.  If you want some  less drastic ragged margin, allow some hyphenation (e.g. `\raggedright\hyphenpenalty50`) and/or allow more stretching  and shrinking  of the space between words (for instance, playing with `\fontdimen`).

Comment: Anyway, without see the true problem, the question is too general for a reasonably precise and concrete answer. Let us see a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) showing how the overfull \hbox are really disturbing you.

Comment: But that's the point: I want a *general* solution. This seems like a basic task. You can probably get an MWE just by doing a long line with `\mbox{...}` around a lot of the letters.

Comment: The general solution is what I tried to explain before.

Comment: That's not a general solution, because it involves having direct access to / control of the text that gets output.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I'll set a bounty on this in a few days if not, maybe.